# React Native RingtoneManager

Tags: react-native, ringtonemanager

I am using https://github.com/millerbennett/react-native-ringtone-manager

But unfortunately RingtoneManager.getRingtones(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL) always return 'undefined'.

I have no error, does anyone knows something about that problem?

I am using emulator, but I can see Ringtones are present in parameters.

**EDIT**

I am back on this problem.

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I read https://github.com/millerbennett/react-native-ringtone-manager and compare to the code of the manager and did not find any problem.

In fact, the object RingtoneManager itself is marked *undefined*.

**EDIT**

So here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View} from 'react-native';
import RingtoneManager from 'react-native-ringtone-manager';


export default class FormRingtones extends React.Component {

static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Rings',
};
constructor(props) {
super(props);

}
rings;

componentDidMount() {
this.getRings();
}

getRings() {
console.log("1 : " + RingtoneManager);
 this.rings =  RingtoneManager.getRingtones(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
 if(this.rings != null) {this.rings = this.rings.map((item,index) =>{<Text>{item.title}</Text>})};
   console.log("2 " + this.rings.length);

}

render() {   
return (
  <View>
    <View >
      {this.rings}
    </View>
  </View>
)
};
}
```

I just installed the latest version as mentioned in a comment, and now the app shows a nice 'Unkown' error and nothing else in debug tools...

Clearing cache and restart all tools saved me.

But now I have [object Object] for RingtoneManager and *undefined* for rings...

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I haven't time to post my solution before now.

The problem is that getRingtones() is simply empty in react-native-ringtone-manager....that is quite annoying when you install this component only for that.

Well, what I did :

In *node_modules\react-native-ringtone-manager\android\src\main\java\com\reactlibrary*, in *RNRingtoneManagerModule.java* :

```
@ReactMethod
public void getRingtones(Callback successCallback) {
    getRingsByType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL, successCallback);
}

@ReactMethod
public void getRingsByType(int ringtoneType, Callback successCallback)          {
    RingtoneManager manager = new RingtoneManager(this.reactContext);
    manager.setType(ringtoneType);
    Cursor cursor = manager.getCursor();
    WritableMap data = Arguments.createMap();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String notificationTitle = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX);
        Uri notificationUri =Uri.parse(cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX) + "/" + cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX));
        data.putString(notificationTitle, notificationUri);

    }
    successCallback.invoke(data);
}
```

And now, all works fine, I can list the ringtones by type, play their sound, etc...

This is the first time of my life that I install something that I must write after :)

**EDIT**

This is how I call RNRingtoneManagerModule :

```
getRingtones(type) {
RingtoneManager.getRingsByType(type, (data) => {
  this.setState({ selected: type, datas: data, selectedItem: data[0] });
});
}
```

Where ItemRingtone is just a view for each item.

Comment: It's not possible for `RingtoneManager` to be undefined and `RingtoneManager.getRingtones()` to return undefined at the same time because the function would not exist. You'll have to show your code. Also note that the library has had commits on only one day two years ago and is used by virtually nobody so it's possible that it's just outdated or has never worked at all.

Comment: hey @Lux , can you please provide me the whole code as i got error like
No callback found with cbID 7 and callID 3 for module <unknown>. Args:

Comment: hey @JJJ did you try the react native ringtone manager?

Comment: @SaloniParikh where is this error ? How do you call the méthod ?

Comment: @SaloniParikh I am sorry but it seems like you gave a negative vote on this thread. That is not cool so I wonder why I should give you an answer...

Comment: i didn't gave you the negative votes

Comment: So I don't understand why this negative vote...I will look my code tomorrow and give you the answer

Comment: i dont no who gave you the negative votes.. but  thanks for this..now i get the ringtones...by adding some extra code

Comment: @SaloniParikh I am really happy it helps you! My whole code is quite specific to my app, so if you have any question, I'll try to do my best to help you:)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Please do not call us thieves. Everyone here is a volunteer and we share our knowledge, because we want to help other people. The votes on your question are not to be taken personally. All it means is that someone didn't find your post helpful for whatever reason. You can try to improve it to make it better for future readers.

Comment: If you want your posts removed, please flag the post for moderator attention and explain succinctly *why* you want it to be deleted. Alternatively: unaccept your own answer, then you can simply press "delete" underneath the tags on your question to delete the question as the system intended.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, I post my whole code. It is not completely finished, I worked on other part of my app since I resolved the main problem of RingToneManager. But it is a good start for who encounter difficulties with Ringtones :

**RNRingtoneManagerModule**

```
package com.reactlibrary;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.database.Cursor;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class RNRingtoneManagerModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
private static final String TYPE_ALARM_KEY = "TYPE_ALARM";
private static final String TYPE_ALL_KEY = "TYPE_ALL";
private static final String TYPE_NOTIFICATION_KEY = "TYPE_NOTIFICATION";
private static final String TYPE_RINGTONE_KEY = "TYPE_RINGTONE";

final static class SettingsKeys {
    public static final String URI = "uri";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String ARTIST = "artist";
    public static final String SIZE = "size";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE = "mimeType";
    public static final String DURATION = "duration";
    public static final String RINGTONE_TYPE = "ringtoneType";
}

public RNRingtoneManagerModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "RingtoneManager";
}

@ReactMethod
public void getRingtones(Callback successCallback) {
    getRingsByType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL, successCallback);
}

@ReactMethod
public void getRingsByType(int ringtoneType, Callback successCallback) {
    RingtoneManager manager = new RingtoneManager(this.reactContext);
    manager.setType(ringtoneType);
    Cursor cursor = manager.getCursor();

    WritableArray result = Arguments.createArray();
    int key= 0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
        WritableMap data = Arguments.createMap();
        String notificationTitle = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX);
        Uri notificationUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX) + "/"
                + cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX));
        String notification = getPathFromUri(this.reactContext, notificationUri);
        data.putInt("key", key);
        data.putString("title", notificationTitle);
        data.putString("uri", notification);
        result.pushMap(data);
        key=key+1;
    }
    successCallback.invoke(result);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public String getPathFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
    final boolean needToCheckUri = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
    // deal with different Uris.
    if (needToCheckUri && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };
        }
    }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

@ReactMethod
public void createRingtone(ReadableMap settings) {
    String uriStr = settings.getString(SettingsKeys.URI);
    File ringtone = new File(uriStr);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, ringtone.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, settings.getString(SettingsKeys.TITLE));
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, settings.getInt(SettingsKeys.SIZE));
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, settings.getString(SettingsKeys.MIME_TYPE));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, settings.getString(SettingsKeys.ARTIST));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, settings.getInt(SettingsKeys.DURATION));
    int ringtoneType = settings.getInt(SettingsKeys.RINGTONE_TYPE);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, isRingtoneType(ringtoneType, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION,
            isRingtoneType(ringtoneType, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, isRingtoneType(ringtoneType, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
    if (ringtone.exists() && getCurrentActivity() != null) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getCurrentActivity().getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtone.getAbsolutePath());
        contentResolver.insert(uri, values);
    }
}

@ReactMethod
public void setRingtone(String uri) {

}

@ReactMethod
public void pickRingtone() {

}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
    final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
    constants.put(TYPE_ALARM_KEY, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    constants.put(TYPE_ALL_KEY, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
    constants.put(TYPE_NOTIFICATION_KEY, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    constants.put(TYPE_RINGTONE_KEY, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    return constants;
}

/**
 * Returns true when the given ringtone type matches the ringtone to compare.
 * Will default to true if the given ringtone type is RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL.
 * 
 * @param ringtoneType          ringtone type given
 * @param ringtoneTypeToCompare ringtone type to compare to
 * @return true if the type matches or is TYPE_ALL
 */
private boolean isRingtoneType(int ringtoneType, int ringtoneTypeToCompare) {
    return ringtoneTypeToCompare == ringtoneType || RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL == ringtoneType;
}
}
```

**FormRingTones**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Button, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, View, ScrollView, StyleSheet,   TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import RingtoneManager from 'react-native-ringtone-manager';
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import Slider from 'react-native-slider';
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';
/*
Param   Type    Description
uri     String  The full file path to the ringtone on the file system.
title   String  The title of the ringtone. Will appear in the picker with this title.
artist  String  The artist of the ringtone.
size    Integer     The size of the ringtone file.
mimeType    String  The mime type of the ringtone, for example: audio/mp3
duration    Integer     The duration of the ringtone in seconds.
ringtoneType    RINGTONE_TYPE   The ringtone type: TYPE_ALL, TYPE_RINGTONE,   TYPE_NOTIFICATION, TYPE_ALARM
*/
class MyListItem extends React.PureComponent {
_onPress = () => {
this.props.onPressItem(this.props.datas);
};


render() {
console.log("this.props.uri " + this.props.uri + "this.props.selected " + this.props.selected)
const textColor = this.props.uri === this.props.selected ? 'black' : 'white';
const backgroundColor = this.props.uri === this.props.selected ? 'orange' : '#444444';

return (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress}>
    <View style={{
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor, borderRadius: 14, paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingVertical: 4,marginBottom:4, shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 9,
      },
      shadowOpacity: 0.48,
      shadowRadius: 11.95,

      elevation: 18,
    }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: textColor }}>{this.props.title}</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: textColor }}>{this.props.duration}    </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 );
 }
}
```

[image: Result]

See my article on medium with updated code :

[Ringtone Manager](https://medium.com/@sebastien.chodkiewicz/react-native-ringtone-manager-create-an-app-eab48b2aad0d)

The code is not clean, I will update when I'll work again on this...

You can see a video illustration on :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72UF2ichH8I&feature=youtu.be

(my first video on the web :) )

Comment: The reason that it Stack Overflow "legally owns your work" is because by posting content on the site you agreed to its license, which means it is now [CCASA licensed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) and thus freely available in the public domain.